Select table names with amount of rows in PostgreSQL
I use PostgreSQL 13. I have several tables. And I want to make a select-request, that get the names of these tables and the number of lines with an NULL updated_date-column.
I can output the number of lines with an NULL date. I do this:
select count(*)
from TABLE_1
where updated_date is null
UNION
select count(*)
from TABLE_2
where updated_date is null;

-------
 count |
-------
     1 |
     2 |
-------  

I can get the names of the tables like this:
select t.tableoid::regclass as table_name
from TABLE_1 t
where updated_date is null;

------------
 table_name |
------------
    TABLE_1 |
------------

select t.tableoid::regclass as table_name
from TABLE_2 t
where updated_date is null;

------------
 table_name |
------------
    TABLE_2 |
    TABLE_2 |
------------

Finally, I need a SQL-request, that will give to me a result:
--------------------
 table_name | count |
--------------------
    TABLE_1 |     1 |
    TABLE_2 |     2 |
--------------------

I try to do this:
select t1.tableoid::regclass, count(*)
from TABLE_1 t1
where updated_date is null
UNION
select t2.tableoid::regclass, count(*)
from TABLE_2 t2
where updated_date is null;

but I get the mistake:
[42803] ERROR: column "t1.tableoid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function 

How can I fix this?

Does this answer your question? Postgresql "column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" and unique field

Seems you need something like:
select t1.tableoid::regclass t_name, count(*) t_count
from TABLE_1 t1
where t1.updated_date is null
group by t_name
union 
select t2.tableoid::regclass t_name, count(*) t_count
from TABLE_2 t2
where t2.updated_date is null
group by t_name;

